# Login script doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I was trying to make a login script for a school website project.

The registration script works just fine. Data gets uploaded to the db and everything.

However the login script, when I press "Sign in", it doesn't transfer me to "profile.php", and the searchbar changes from "http://localhost/buddyfinder/main.php" to "http://localhost/buddyfinder/main.php?loginemail=testing%40gmail.com&loginpassword=Troll123&btn-login=SIGN+IN#"

Also I tried making a script that would change the "Sign In" and "Register" button change to "Logout" when the user is signed in, but it doesn't work. Maybe cause I don't actually get logged in? I have no idea.

I had to upload the files to Google Drive, Since they don't work properly with the "Code Sample" function.

Link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HDQtx21igNVy0sQX4q4LSVmqCo6vZUTA?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance guys!
Sorry if you find stupid mistakes. Still green in php and js :D.

Regards,
Szymon.

Comment: Please write the code in your question and don't refer to external link + I think your problem is in your form action attribute, If you want to transfer datas to profile.php then your action attribute should be profile.php not main.php

Comment: We can't access `http://localhost` links because those are local to your computer. Please, edit this question to include any relevant code. Not everyone has or wants a Google account to access your code, and those that do may not bother because who knows what lives at the end of that link.

Comment: I understand what you mean. The problem is that when I paste the code in here, parts of it appear as code, and parts as normal text. Was going to bed, so I decided to kust post it on Google drive as it takes less time than to fix all the code here. Also where did you get the "http://localhost" from? Will fix that tomorrow :).

Comment: @M4HdYaR datas are supposed to be transferred to login_process.php. The "profile.php" is the site I want users to be redirected to when successfully logged in.

Comment: Try if(isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {     header("Location: profile.php");     exit; } in top of your php file and if you want to transfer data to login_proccess so your action attribute of your html form should be login_proccess.php

Comment: Thanks! Will try that when I get to the PC :). I would like the person to still be able to access the main page tho. So that they get redirected only when they press "sign in" and successfully sign in. That's why I tried putting it into the login_process.php ;).